# Vue won't render custom component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a custom component for some repetitive html. But the component won't show and I get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

found in

---> <Child>
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

My main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['text'],
  template: `<div>{{ text }}<div>`
});

new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

My App.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <child :text="message"></child>
    <Navbar/>
    <v-content>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>
    <Footer/>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import styles from './app.css'
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { Navbar, Footer },
  computed: {
    theme(){
      return (this.$vuetify.theme.dark) ? 'dark' : 'light'
    },
  },
  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>
```

What is going on? How to define a custom component?

My question "has mostly code"; so, my thoughts on vue.js: I notice that there are quite a few different ways or styles to build vue.js applications. I wish their examples would give more context on where to put the example code, I'm a seasoned developer, but new to web dev and js, and find that a lack of examples on the vue.js site really makes it hard to learn this framework.

Comment: Why don't you create a component called Child? I think it would be easier.

Comment: check here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2754

Comment: If you create the child component as an SFC (single file component), with its own `.vue` file, then the template is compiled by Webpack, converting it to a `render` function. The runtime-only build of Vue does not include a template compiler, making it smaller. This smaller build is typically the one used in the browser as it doesn't need to compile the templates if they've already been compiled by Webpack. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only and https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: @skirtle: YES! That did it. So, you the  Vue.component approach didn't work for me, as I use WebPack. Strange, but this works.

Comment: Webpack doesn't compile all templates, it specifically targets the templates of SFCs. If you specify the template inline in `main.js` it won't be compiled by Webpack and it'll need to be compiled in the browser, requiring the full Vue build. You can still use `Vue.component` with an SFC, using `Vue.component` is unrelated to the problem. If you want to enable the full build I suggest using the UI that comes with the CLI, run it using `vue ui`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1- create a component in a separate .vue file

2- register it globally in main.js

3- then call it in any component directly.

**1.**

```
<template><div>{{ text }}<div></template>
<script>
    export default{
    props:['text']
    },

</script>
```

**2. in main.js**

```
//...
Vue.component('child-component',require('./path/to/chaild/compoent').default);
//...
```

**3** Now you can call it in any component because it is registered globally.

```
<template>
    <div>
       <child-component text='some text to pass as prop.'/>
      //...
    </div>
</template>
//...
```